# How do I add the stripe.js to an ember-cli app?

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli, bower-install, broccolijs

First I included the stripe.js file via bower:

```
bower install --save stripe.js=https://js.stripe.com/v2/
```

Which created "vendor/stripe/index" (note *not* index.js, but index).  Then I added this to my broccoli file:

```
app.import('vendor/stripe/index')
```

Which gets me this error:

```
You must pass a file to `app.import`. For directories specify them to the constructor under the `trees` option.Error: You must pass a file to `app.import`. For directories specify them to the constructor under the `trees` option.
  at EmberApp.import (/home/jim/Desktop/TaskVelocity/task-velocity/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:521:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jim/Desktop/TaskVelocity/task-velocity/Brocfile.js:9:11)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

What am I missing to get this to work?

Tried the suggestion from the user, and received this error:

```
Path or pattern "vendor/stripe/stripe.js" did not match any files Error: Path or pattern "vendor/stripe/stripe.js" did not match any files 
at Object.multiGlob   (/home/jim/Desktop/TaskVelocity/web/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli‌​-concat/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:221:13) –
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I manually created everything, because the /v2/index.js really messed things up. Not ideal, I know, but Stripe works quite nicely in my app now.

In my Brocfile.js:

```
   app.import('vendor/stripe/stripe.js');
```

And in my app's file structure, this file is at:

```
   [appname]/vendor/stripe/stripe.js
```

There is, if I recall, a stripe npm package, too. I don't know how up to date it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not officially endorsed AFAICT and may therefore break at any moment, but you can install the script like this instead:

`bower install --save stripe.js=https://js.stripe.com/v2/stripe.js`

This will create an `index.js` file that you should then be able to use normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename the file with [`broccoli-file-mover`](https://github.com/rjackson/broccoli-file-mover). See http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#customizing-a-built-in-asset

Comment: Path or pattern "vendor/stripe/stripe.js" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "vendor/stripe/stripe.js" did not match any files
  at Object.multiGlob (/home/jim/Desktop/TaskVelocity/web/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-concat/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:221:13)